# Routes are not working, variable from controller are coming up as undefined

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing

PostController

```php
public function index()
{
  $posts=Post::all();
  return view('home')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

web.php

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('posts','PostController');
```

home

```php
@foreach($posts as $post)
  <p>{{$post['content']}}</p>
@endforeach
```

I get this error

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException

Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lts\resources\views\home.blade.php)
```

`$posts` are undefined

Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace `{{ $posts }}` with `{{ $posts ?? '' }}`

Thanks for help everyone I was able to fix it by adding

```
Route::get('/home', 'PostController@index');
```

I would love to know why this problem was caused in first place `Route:: resource('posts','PostController');` should have handled it.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting variables from `Posts` table?

Comment: so by adding this Route::get('/home', 'PostController@index'); before Route::resource('posts','PostController'); index function seems to be working. Shouldn't this be handled with Route::resource('posts','PostController');

Comment: _Where_ do you get this error? `PostController@index` shows `home.blade`, as does `HomeController@index`. Do you have `$posts` set in your `HomeController`?

Comment: there's nothing in homecontroller

Comment: @HaseebAhmed Which controller used for retrieve post? PostController or HomeController.

Comment: @Amit Senjaliya i made post controller with --resource and index method with the code is in post controller.

Comment: @HaseebAhmed When this error occurs? what is a URL?  Please share with us.

Comment: url is http://localhost/lts/public/home

Comment: @HaseebAhmed That is why an error occurs. I will post answer.

Comment: I'm retrieving posts on home page, url doesn't change.

Comment: You also might want to take a look at installing/setting up Laravel. `/public` should be the DocumentRoot and not appear in your URLs.

Comment: i'll fix it before I deploy it on a live server.

Comment: @HaseebAhmed Can you read my answer. Tell me any question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

**First One:**

If you want to use `HomeController` for `/home` route then add following code in the HomeController.

HomeController:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts=Post::all();
    return view('home')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

**Second One**

You have used the `resource` method in the `web.php` so your 'PostController' URL starts from `posts` But you have used `/home`.
So change your route like this:

In `web.php`

```
Route::get('/home', 'PostController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('posts','PostController');
```

Comment: @HaseebAhmed Which method used for you? First one or second one.

Comment: looks like this was the issue, bad idea to retrieve posts on home page?

Comment: @HaseebAhmed You are right second method more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Chnage in your controller

```
public function index()
    {
      $posts=Post::all();
     return view('home')->with('posts', $posts);
    }
```

change in your blade

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post['content'] }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: `{{ $post['content'] }}` change this.

Comment: How would that help when "_$posts is undefined_"?

Comment: `return view('home')->with('posts', $posts);`

Comment: {{ $post['content'] }} or {{ $post->content }}

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of what you have given for loop

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->content}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
return view('home')->with('posts', $posts);
```

with

```
return view('home', ['posts' => $posts]);
```

and

```
<p>{{$post['content']}}</p>
```

with

```
<p>{{ optional($post)->content }}</p>
```

Comment: Can you verify you are hitting this controller? public function index()
    {
dd('The expected controller is executing');
      $posts=Post::all();
      return view('home')->with('posts', $posts);
    }